# Noticed Something In winuser.h

Tags: c++, winapi

Recently I started learning WIN API from Microsoft documentation and I decided to look at every detail with my IDE features.
LoadIconA is a function that takes HINSTANCE and LPCSTR as parameters. we pass IDI_APPLICATION as the second parameter. This is a macro That expands as

```
#define IDI_APPLICATION MAKEINTRESOURCE(32512) // winuser.h
```

Moreover, MAKEINTRESOURCE expands as ANSI or UNICODE equivalent. I am looking at ANSI equivalent.

```
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEA(i) ((LPSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i)))) // winuser.h
```

This where I noticed that integer I (here 32512) is ultimately typecasted into LPSTR which is passed into the LoadIconA function. But when I do the same as

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
     LPCSTR hello = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(32512);
     std::cout << hello << std::endl;
}
```

My program crashes.
Does someone have any idea what's going over here?

Also, I didn't notice any library dependencies. sorry for the Ques Title, I didn't find any Proper title.

Comment: _"...Converts an integer value to a resource type compatible with the resource-management functions. ..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcea  _"...The return value should be passed only to functions __which explicitly indicate that they accept MAKEINTRESOURCE as a parameter__. .."_

Comment: `1 != 32512` isnt that a difference? You are not "doing the same"

Comment: @idclev463035818 - it's for accessing strings in a Windows Resource file and built-in string resources using the WinAPI only.

Comment: I think `hello` should be of `LPSTR` type instead of `LPCSTR`

Comment: @idclev463035818 It doesnt work either.

Comment: @RichardCritten which explicitly indicate that they accept MAKEINTRESOURCE as a parameter.  How does This Happen.

Comment: i didnt claim that it will work when you do the same, but I don't understand why you expect to get the same result when you do something different

Comment: @vectorX `LoadIconA` _"...The name of the icon resource to be loaded. Alternatively, this parameter can contain the resource identifier in the low-order word and zero in the high-order word. __Use the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro__ to create this value...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona

Comment: Sounds to me like inside `LoadIconA` it determines whether the LPCSTR argument is in the range created by MAKEINTRESOURCE, and if so it never tries to use the value directly as a string, but instead uses it as an index into some other container of strings.  When you `cout << hello` though, you're not doing that - you're assuming it's a pointer to a text, and following an invalid pointer.  Hence, crash.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Exactly - it's a kludge dating back to 16 bit Windows where every byte was precious.

Comment: Very very very old Windows "trick". It's *either* a resource id *or* a pointer to a string. In Windows, the first 64K of address space is always invalid. So you know it's a resource id if the pointer value is < 0x10000, so it's expected to crash with this code. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110217-00/?p=11463

Answer (score 3):

This macro casts an integer to a pointer. Obviously (unless you happen to guess an integer representing a valid pointer) the result is an invalid pointer, in the sense that dereferencing it causes undefined behavior (normally a crash).

`<<` tries to dereference this invalid pointer (to print it as an array of characters) and crashes.

WinAPI functions that can work with `MAKEINTRESOURCE` have to check if pointers they receive have one of those special values, and only dereference them if it's not the case.

Comment: Actually there are Thousands of such consecutive conversion. so, This can't be special.

Comment: @vectorX Then the WinAPI functions probably check for a range of values.

Comment: All such 'special' values are less than 65536 (2^16) and thus it's easy to judge whether to perform additional lookup or just attempt to use the value as a pointer.

Comment: @vectorX: All those functions aren't special; they just forward to `FindResourceA/W` which _is_ special.